# System Environment Test

Tags: compiling, fortran

I am trying to compile WRF on Ubuntu 16,while checking system environment tests(Fortran and C Test),I have successfully did TEST #1.
But when I tried to do TEST 2:I got following error:

```
[gopi65@wise1 TESTS]$ gfortran TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90 
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:4

   USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: c_char, c_ptr, c_int32_t, &
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:8

   TYPE, BIND(C) :: r_info
  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:9

      INTEGER(C_INT64_T)                         :: offset
             1
Error: Parameter 'c_int64_t' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:10

      INTEGER(C_INT64_T)                         :: data_offset
             1
Error: Parameter 'c_int64_t' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:11

      INTEGER(C_INT32_T)                         :: data_count
             1
Error: Parameter 'c_int32_t' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:12

      INTEGER(C_INT32_T)                         :: data_type
             1
Error: Parameter 'c_int32_t' at (1) has not been declared or is a variable, which does not reduce to a constant expression
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:13

      CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), DIMENSION(10) :: name
                          1
Error: Constant expression required at (1)
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:14

      CHARACTER(KIND=C_CHAR), DIMENSION(10) :: date
                          1
Error: Constant expression required at (1)
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:15

   END TYPE r_info
     1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:24

      TYPE(bunch_of_stuff), ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: ddt_things
                                      1
Error: Attribute at (1) is not allowed in a TYPE definition
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:25

   END TYPE outer_wrapper
                        1
Error: Derived type definition at (1) has no components
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:27

   TYPE(outer_wrapper), DIMENSION(15) :: combo
                     1
Error: Derived type 'outer_wrapper' at (1) is being used before it is defined
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:29

   ALLOCATE(combo(1)%ddt_things(10))
                1
Error: Syntax error in ALLOCATE statement at (1)
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:30

   ALLOCATE(combo(2)%ddt_things(10))
                1
Error: Syntax error in ALLOCATE statement at (1)
 In file TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90:31

   ALLOCATE(combo(3)%ddt_things(10))
                1
Error: Syntax error in ALLOCATE statement at (1)
[gopi65@wise1 TESTS]$
```

May I get the solution please.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for [so]?

Comment: I assume you are following the steps described in [configuring-wrf-3.8-on-ubuntu-server-16.04](https://github.com/camposdelano/configuring-wrf-3.8-on-ubuntu-server-16.04)? It looks like your `gfortran` is not recognizing the [ISO C binding extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fC_005fBINDING.html) - please [edit] your question to include the output of `gfortran --version`. Does it work if you do `gfortran -std=f2003 TEST_2_fortran_only_free.f90` ?

Comment: ... also the output of `type gfortran` so we can see whether you have an alias that sets `-std=` to something inappropriate